# Azure functions app read O365 Group Mailbox

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to access Outlook API endpoints to read inbox of a group mail box?

```
{"error":{"code":"OAuthMissingForThisApiVersion","message":"Authentication for this API version requires OAuth."}}
```

how can I pass OAuth token for this request?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official doc, you need to acquire a token and set the Authorization header in your requests:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$select=subject,from,receivedDateTime&$top=25&$orderby=receivedDateTime%20DESC

Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi...b66LoPVA
X-AnchorMailbox: jason@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started